# Cannot assign value of type 'Character' to type 'String'

Tags: swift

I want to loop over an array using indexPath.row, but I got stuck at this message: "Cannot assign value of type 'Character' to type 'String'"

I know that there are more questions like this, but I can't figure it out with the responses of other people.

**Here is my code:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = nieuwsTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")
    splitArray().forEach { (NevoboNieuws) in
        let titles = NevoboNieuws.title
        cell?.textLabel?.text = titles[indexPath.row]
    }
    return cell!
}
```

[image]

Comment: it looks like you want titles which is actually a title, you can directly assign titles in label. But how you will make sure its from correct NevoboNiews object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`title` is obviously a string. So the `indexPath.row` of a string is a single character.

What is the purpose of the `forEach` expression? Be aware that `cellForRowAt` is called once for each row.

You probably want

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = nieuwsTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    let item = splitArray()[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = item.title
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much,  this solution is way better than I had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4 -- Cast Character to string

```
cell?.textLabel?.text = String(titles[indexPath.row])
```